# Zend Framework rewrite urls to SEO friendly URL

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-rewriting

With the Zend Framework, I am trying to build a URL to SEO friendly URL

`http://ww.website.com/public/index/categories/category/2`
should be mapped by `http://ww.website.com/public/index/categories/category.html`

`http://ww.website.com/public/index/products/category/2/subcategory/2`
should be mapped by `http://ww.website.com/public/index/products/product.html`

In my Bootstrap file I have tried this

```
protected function _initRoutes()
{ 
    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance ();
    $router = $frontController->getRouter ();
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
        'index/categories/category/(\d*)/',
        array('module' => 'default','controller' => 'index','action' => 'categories'), 
        array(1 => 'category'),
        'index/categories/%d-%s.html');

    $router->addRoute('category', $route);
}
```

Now my question is how to rewrite this URL? I am also retrieving the products or categories based on the IDs in the URL using:

```
$id = $this->_getParam('category', 0 );
```

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not need Regex route for what you need.
If you want for example  this url: 
`http://mysite.com/category/cars.html` to go to `http://mysite.com/categories/category/id/2` is enough to use Zend_Controller_Router_Route

Now is only one problem Zend Router will not know id of you category to map, for this you need to store your custom routes to database or a file; Each custom route will contain url that map and required parameters (controller name, action name, id of category).

After we have that we can build a function that register a custom route to bootstrap file, or in some plugin like this one:

```
public function setRoute($params){
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
    $params = array(
        'controller' => $params['controller'],
        'action'     => $params['action'],
        'id'         => $params['id']
        );
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route($params['url'], $params);
    $router->addRoute($params['url'], $route);
}
```

Now let suppose that `$params['url']` has value: `http://mysite.com/category/cars.html` when is requested from browser that url ZF will match our custom route and forward request to specified controller in `$params['controller']`, and call specified action in `$params['action']` and will set as parameter named id value from `$params['id']` wich can be retrieved from controller with `$id = $this->_getParam('id',0);`

Answer (score 1):

I think you go with wrong path because SEO friendly not meaning for .html or .php if your product name start after base url like to "http://www.promotepassion.com/classical/rock" means base path then category name then product name, if we  use then all search engine quickly call page.